# How is a selector different from an element?

Tags: jquery

In the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/is/), some features have worked on selectors since version 1.0.  But added to version 1.6 is the same feature that now works on an element.  How is this something that was added?  Is there a difference between a tag selector and an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector is a string. An element is the DOM object that you use selectors to select. The documentation you linked to has an example:

> Checks against an existing collection
>   of alternating list elements. Blue,
>   alternating list elements slide up
>   while others turn red.
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <style>li { cursor:pointer; }</style>
>   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <ul id="browsers">
>   <li>Chrome</li>
>   <li>Safari</li>
>   <li>Firefox</li>
>   <li>Opera</li>
> </ul>
> <script>
>   var $alt = $("#browsers li:nth-child(2n)").css("background", "#00FFFF");
>   $('li').click(function() {
>     if ( $alt.is( this ) ) {
>       $(this).slideUp();
>     } else {
>       $(this).css("background", "red");
>     }
>   });
> </script>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Notice how the argument to `$alt.is` is the element that was clicked, `this`, not a jQuery selector string.

Answer (score 2):

`element` in the documentation is probably referring to a DOM object. So for example this works:

```
var someElement = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[0]; // points to a single DOM element

$(...).is( someElement );
```

Note that this example makes very little sense, given that you usually don’t mix DOM functions with jQuery, but I’m sure there are some useful cases for this. And you should get the idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

element:

```
$....something(document.getElementById("something"));
```

or in some contexts:

```
$...something(this);
```

but a selector is just a string that describes an element or set of elements:

```
$...something(".class");
$...something("#theid");
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably that you can simply match agains an DOM-element without jQuery first turning it into a jQuery-element for you. Probably save you some time and memory. My best guess at least.